# How to add elements to an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can this method add items to an array in C# ?

```
class Set 
{
    int [] arr = {1,2,5,4};
    int [] arr2 = {3,2,4,8};

    public void AddElement()
    {
        arr.add(90);
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh?   You don't add methods to an array of primitive data types.  Please be more specific.

Comment: My apologies ! I'm trying to create a method titled: public void AddElement ()  that adds a element to either of the arrays .

Comment: Please explain [why you are trying to do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) because what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the array has a fixed length,you can use the Resizing method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are fixed size.

From [Array Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview)

> The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are
> established when the array instance is created. These values can't be
> changed during the lifetime of the instance.

If you want to add element to array, you need to create a new one, copy values and then store new value.

But in C# there is Collections, for instance List class (it's in System.Collections.Generic).

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
list.Add(100);
```

There is solution for arrays.

```
class Set 
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 5, 4 };
    int[] arr2 = { 3, 2, 4, 8 };

    public void AddElement() 
    {
        var newArray = new int[arr.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(arr, newArray, arr.Length);
        newArray[newArray.Length - 1] = 90;
        arr = newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I wouldn't be able to use the ones previously declared? I would have to always create a new array?

Comment: I've updated my answer for arrays. But check System.Collections.Generic. C# has great library.

Comment: so the previous array plus 90 added will be the new elements in the newArray?

Comment: @CassandraB If you want to split hairs about using an **array**, then let's go there. If you can add an item to it, it's not really an array at all in the pure computer science sense; it's some type of **collection** that you've been lulled into calling an array by some half-baked platform. Real arrays have fixed size. If you want a collection, .Net has plenty of them. The suggestion to use `List<T>` will do what you need.

Comment: If you use `Array.Copy` when all you really want is to add an element, you'll be copying all the existing array values to the new copy, and at least temporarily you'll have two copies in memory.  One will eventually be garbage collected, unless you've also assigned it to another variable.  Then you'll have one variable holding a reference to the old copy, one holding a reference to the new copy, with two copies of identical data in memory, and updates to the one will no longer be updates to the other.  I don't think most would expect a method called `AddElement` to have that side effect.

Comment: In short, just use `List<T>` instead of an array if you want a collection that can change size.  Its `Add` method will do just what you'd expect.

Comment: There really is no need to manually create the new array, copy the array content and re-assign the `arr` variable. Because that's exactly what [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-7.0) does, so use it instead of reinventing the wheel... ;-)